# Website is being redirected with document referrer and it's ruining search engine results

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, search-engine, referrer

If you search on Google 'new york state beach cleanup', you'll see that the first result is for the website http://najomawi.com, but the title doesn't look quite right for such a site.  You'll also notice that if you click this link it instead takes you to a website for Nike shoes.  It only happens if you use the Google results link though (and I believe it happens in Bing, Yahoo and others).  If you put http://najomawi.com directly into your browser bar, it takes you to the correct site.  Confused, I checked the page source code (both with 'View Page Source' and Chrome's inspector) and found this...

```
<script>
    var s=document.referrer;
    if(s.indexOf("google")>0 || s.indexOf("bing")>0 || s.indexOf("aol")>0 || s.indexOf("yahoo")>0)
    {
        self.location='http://www.theredkicks.com';
    }
</script>
```

I have no idea how this got there.  It appears in the the head tags of the home page, which is index.html.  There is no PHP code, no other JS, nothing other than CSS stylesheets that I am aware of.  The entire site is pretty much static HTML and CSS sheets.  So how did this get there?  And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: It should be there somewhere in the html. It's appearing at the very top, above the `DOCTYPE`. It got there because someone hacked the site (obviously), and if there's no serverside code at all, it should be sitting there in the HTML files.

Comment: I thought that too, but it's not there.  The index file looks normal.

Comment: The code is likely being injected; Have a look at your web server or proxy servers - whatever would be between your users and the site.  For example in Apache, it can be an output filter

Comment: It is somebody using ASP. Look at the cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSATCSAAC=INMLBOADDKNKMPACCK

Comment: @VictorSchröder and the `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET` header, but as I never used ASP i'm not sure if the existents of it will mean that everything is passed through ASP.

Comment: @t.niese, it's hard to tell in which step this injection is going on. You should claim urgent action to your host provider.

Comment: @VictorSchröder just thought you probably could clarify for the OP if every request is piped through ASP when `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`.

Comment: @t.niese, as far I know, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript code is very simple. It just checks if `document.referrer` contains the name of the most relevant search engines and, if so, redirects the load to another page, in this case, `http://www.theredkicks.com`.

Your site certainly was hacked somehow or your host provider is not very honest.

Notice that there's nothing attached to the query string in this redirect, so this is not an "affiliate" (wrong) way to make money. The only person that is gaining something with this is the redirect target.

Also, it's very interesting that your page is aparently being processed trought ASP. That is strange, as long as you say that your site is made only by static HTML and CSS.

Look at the cookie, is something like this:

```
ASPSESSIONIDSATCSAAC=INMLBOADDKNKMPACCK
```

And also the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2014 01:30:49 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 15168
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-control: private
```

I don't know where you are hosting your site, but you should claim urgent solution for this problem there.

Comment: It turned out this was the problem afterall.  I don't actually own the site, it was a relative who had the problem, so I didn't have direct access to the files.  However we managed to figure out that there was a few ASP files lying around, some perhaps left there by the host, but one in particular that was hidden and had a strange name of random letters.  It's possible some malware/virus/trojan is on their machine and wormed its way onto their website or maybe their account info was stolen for the purpose of injecting this stuff.  Either way, after deleting the ASP, this problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is an injection being done conditionally, pointing to your DNS server/records being compromised.

Your DNS primary and secondary records are being routed through siteprotect.com. I have no idea if you have chosen siteprotect as your DNS handlers, but siteprotect.com doesn't actually resolve at the moment. I also have no idea who "siteprotect" are.

If your actual host is not "siteprotect" and you have not heard of them, reset your DNS records to those of your host and change your passwords etc. If your host is "siteprotect" they may be aware of the problem and working on it.